# SELECT TOP 10 of each group of a certain field with data across 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

SQL Server 2017.

Table `Captures` contains records with `CaptureId` (Primary Key) and `SourceId` which identifies which source the record came from (many records can have the same `SourceId`).

Table `Source` contains all the descriptive info about each source.  The common field between the two tables is `SourceId`.

I need several groups of Top 10 records from `Captures` - the groups are determined by filtering on the `Source` table.

This is the query for just the `Source` table part:

```
SELECT
SourceId,
Type,
State
FROM Source
WHERE Type = 1
AND State = 'TX'
```

I need TOP 10 * from `Captures` for each `SourceId` returned from the above query, and need to get this result set using one combined query.

I attempted this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM Capture
WHERE SourceId IN(
    SELECT SourceId
    FROM Source
    WHERE Type = 1
    AND State = 'TX'
)
```

but I of course only got a total of 10 records, whereas I need 10 records for *each* `SourceId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `APPLY`. Similar to `JOIN`, but the applied sub-select (`TopCaptures`) is executed once for every row in `Sources`. So you can get top 10 captures per source.

**Variant A** - using a CTE:

```
; WITH Sources AS 
(
    SELECT SourceId
    FROM Source
    WHERE Type = 1
      AND State = 'TX'
)
SELECT *
FROM Sources
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 10 *
    FROM Captures
    WHERE Captures.SourceId = Sources.SourceId
) AS TopCaptures;
```

**Variant B** - using another sub-select:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT SourceId
    FROM Source
    WHERE Type = 1
      AND State = 'TX'
) AS Sources
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 10 *
    FROM Captures
    WHERE Captures.SourceId = Sources.SourceId
) AS TopCaptures;
```

**Edit:** If you want `INNER JOIN`-like behaviour, use `CROSS APPLY` instead of `OUTER APPLY`: Using `CROSS APPLY`, no Sources-rows will be returned, that do not have at least 1 Capture.